# SwiftUI: Countdown Circle with Animation

Tags: swiftui

I've created a progress circle for my App, that will count down from 28 to 0 (number of days until Payday)

I've got the circles to display how I'd like, but I want it to animate when I navigate to the view, is there a way to do this?

More a UI question, but do you think maybe an arrow within the circle to indicate the direction would look any good?

P.s - any ideas how to truncate all the zeros off my Double?

[image of how this looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HqWe.png)

Thanks!

```
ZStack {
    
    let progressPeriod = Double(PayData.daysUntilPay) ?? 0
    let progressPeriod2 = 1 - (progressPeriod / 28)
    
    Circle()
        .stroke(lineWidth: 30.0)
        .opacity(0.3)
        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.941, green: 0.426, blue: 0.004))
        .frame(width:150)
        .frame(height: 200)
    
    Circle()
        .trim(from: 0.0, to: progressPeriod2)
        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.941, green: 0.426, blue: 0.004))
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
        .frame(width:150)
        .frame(height: 200)
    
    Text("\(progressPeriod) days")
        .bold()
}
```

Comment: for the P.S part, check out `NumberFormatter`. It may help you. Or if your minimum required iOS version is 15 or newer you can use the new APIs of the foundation: `progressPeriod.formatted(.number.rounded().precision(.fractionLength(0)))`

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is your code for navigating to the view struct, and please show a complete view struct including the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine following code with your countdown:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var progressValue: Float = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow
                .opacity(0.1)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack {
                ProgressBar(progress: self.$progressValue)
                    .frame(width: 150.0, height: 150.0)
                    .padding(40.0)
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.incrementProgress()
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.rectangle.fill")
                        Text("Increment")
                    }
                    .padding(15.0)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 2.0)
                    )
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func incrementProgress() {
        let randomValue = Float([0.012, 0.022, 0.034, 0.016, 0.11].randomElement()!)
        self.progressValue += randomValue
    }
}
struct ProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var progress: Float
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 20.0)
                .opacity(0.3)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(self.progress, 1.0)))
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
                .animation(.linear)

            Text(String(format: "%.0f %%", min(self.progress, 1.0)*100.0))
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
        }
    }
}
```